# Tried using many sticky footer tutorials, cannot fix footer

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I have been having trouble with getting a footer to stay at the bottom of the browser on a template I have been using. If there is a lot of content to 'push' the footer down it looks ok on firefox, but I can see in chrome it is in 'mid air' above the bottom of the page and looks very bad.

Something must be wrong with it but even after I've looked at many sticky footer tutorials not one seems to fix the issue, it just 'breaks' the footer, usually making it disjointed. I am still a beginner at html/php so would greatly appreciate any help, I'm desperate to solve the problem.

I have pasted the style.css and the sample page on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3KZh3/4/

Comment: I feel your pain.  I am not a beginner and this is one of those things that always haunts me.  I recently spent a ton of time trying to get it solved for good... trying to find it -

Comment: Yeah, in the beginning it worked or seemed to work, now checking in other browsers its like it was never 'sticky' and everything I change breaks it.

Answer (score 1):

```
   Try this one dont forget to add  `position:relative` to it's parent div or element 
   #parent-div{
          position:relative;
    }

    #footer {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the suggestion but as when Ive tried adding the code from the many sticky footer tutorials I get this result: http://i50.tinypic.com/15ox8qr.png

Comment: Then add online images path, or jst use plain color, I just want to see your HTML and css code with parent div, dont wna see images

Answer (score 1):

fix the min-height of the division above footer. I think it will work.

Otherwise set the position property of footer to absolute and bottom to 0. try this hope it will work.

Comment: Though I seem to need to increase the min-height until it pushes the footer down to the bottom of the page still, if I make it longer enough for one browser you have to scroll down to see it in another browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice but I get more or less the same result as the above comment or when I try adding the code from the sticky footer tutorials: i50.tinypic.com/15ox8qr.png

Comment: Read and learn [this](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Answer (score 0):

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

Will make you footer stay to the bottom. But you have to make some changes to the rest of your content accordingly.

Have a look at this example: [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3KZh3/5/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/varaH/1/

I'm also trying to get to the bottom of this.  this is my basic example.  It gets more complicated in responsive sites... but i keep this to remember that it is possible... hopefully this will help ?

Comment: after looking through this thread - i'm pretty confused now... so maybe this isn't what you want... but it's what people call a "sticky" footer... although... that doesn't seem like a good name for it...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `position:fixed`
Try to experiment by adding lots of dummy data in the body so that you scroll the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Some Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #footer{
            position:fixed;
            bottom:0px;
            background-color: black;
            color:white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Some Page</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <div id="footer">
        &copy; company name
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope thishelps

Comment: If I add that the css then the footer floats at bottom over the page, instead of staying as a part of the page itself, your code is maybe incompatible with the rest of the footer's code. thanks though.